# Reactjs useReducer hook error ReferenceError: Cannot access 'reducer' before initialization

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am learning Reactjs hoooks by reading online tutorials. Here is my code. I am sure it can be improved. I got this error:-

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'reducer' before initialization

```
    function ProfileForm(props) {
const form = useForm();
const {
  register,
  handleSubmit,
  errors,
  formState: { isSubmitting }
} = form;

const [profile, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, profileInitSate)

const profileInitSate = {
  displayName: '',
  birthDate: '',
  height: 0,
}

const reducer = (state, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
      case 'displayName' : 
        return {...state, displayName: action.value};

      case 'realName':
        return {...state, realName: action.value};

      case 'birthDate':
        return {...state, birthDate: action.value};          
      default:
        return state;          
    }  
}

useEffect(() => {
  if(props.location.state.profile){
      dispatch({type: 'dispalyName', 
      value: props.location.state.profile.displayName})
      dispatch({type: 'realName', 
      value: props.location.state.profile.realName})
      dispatch({type: 'birthDate', 
      value: props.location.state.profile.birthDate})
      dispatch({type: 'height', 
      value: props.location.state.profile.height})
  }

}, [profile]);
```

Please let me know how can I improve this code also why do I get this error?

Comment: Move the declaration of `const reducer` before you call `useReducer`

Comment: Same for `profileInitSate `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Asyush pointed out in the comment section and destructure it to keep it a cleaner, the rest seems good although i would suggest keeping the reducer in a seperate file

```
      function ProfileForm(props) {
    const form = useForm();
    const {
      register,
      handleSubmit,
      errors,
      formState: { isSubmitting }
    } = form;

    const profileInitSate = {
      displayName: '',
      birthDate: '',
      height: 0,
    }

    const reducer = (state, action) =>{
        switch(action.type){
          case 'displayName' : 
            return {...state, displayName: action.value};

          case 'realName':
            return {...state, realName: action.value};

          case 'birthDate':
            return {...state, birthDate: action.value};          
          default:
            return state;          
        }  
    }
// Change the name to avoid conflict because of destructure
   const [profileReducer, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, profileInitSate)    

   let {profile} = props.location.state;

   let {displayName,realName,birthDate,height}=profile;

    useEffect(() => {
      if(props.location.state.profile){
          dispatch({type: 'dispalyName', 
          value: displayName})
          dispatch({type: 'realName', 
          value: realName})
          dispatch({type: 'birthDate', 
          value: birthDate})
          dispatch({type: 'height', 
          value: height})
       }

      }, [profileReducer]);
```

Comment: Since I am learning reducer, moving reducer to another file means that I make a reducer.js  and includes  ̧`const profileInitSate =`  and  `const reducer = (state, action) =>{`  in this file. Later I `import reducer from './reducer.js'`. Or something else ?

Comment: Yeah pretty much , that should do it , plus having having the `profileInitSate` as the initial state like `const reducer = (state=profileInitSate, action) =>{`

Comment: Thanks! May I know what benefit will it give? Why is it recommended to move reducer to a separate file?

Comment: lets say , if later you decide to use something like Redux, you may need need to combine the Reducers, so it would be more efficent to just import only the reducer files and combine them rather than having to use files which have rest of the stuff bunched into it or even if you are using the ContextAPI as an alternative its way waay more cleaner to just have 3 seperate files : Context, State and the Reducer, From which you can easily understand the flow

Comment: Thx for the info! All of it went over my head, coz I am just scratching the surface of Reactjs. Hopefully, over time I will be more knowledgeable and understand the advanced topic of Reactjs. Thx anyway!